# SSH using keys in external storage - permissions?

Tags: ssh, privacy

I have a set of SSH keys to login to accounts and servers. However, ever since I moved my main work profile to a USB drive (for sync and ease of use among other reasons) I have been unable to *directly* use the SSH keys in the profile for authentication, having to create local copies instead.

Normal SSH workflow usually goes

```
ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/id_server_key 
ssh username@domain
```

Which works without problems. However, to prevent each machine from having a copy of my keys I moved them to an xexternal drive, USB formatted as `vfat`. Then workflow *should* become like this:

```
ssh-add  /run/media/myself/USB/.ssh/id_server_key
ssh username@domain
```

...Which doesn't work. SSH complains about doing something to protect me:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for 'id_server_key' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: id_server_key
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Which, while I can understand, it's not *really* protecting me in this case.

The USB drive automounts in my distro, with a fmask of (I think) `022`. I could unmount and remount the USB drive with a fmask of `077` but that would (1) require superuser privilege each time and (2) affect every single file in the device, not only the SSH keys.

I've tried creating a symlink to the key, even with previous use of `umask` as I've seen in some tips&tricks:

```
cd .ssh
umask 077
ln -s /run/media/myself/USB/.ssh/id_server_key
```

But the permissions can not be used this way for a symbolic link, so I get nothing.

So, what **options** do I have here available if the goal is to **not** have a physical copy of the key on the machine? One of the machines is a family laptop that goes to various places, so I have an interest in avoiding some of the keys being discovered.

So far I've considered the following:

- Is there for example an option to force SSH (`ssh-add` primarily) to accept the keys from the external device? (I presume there should be - most programs follow a "I-know-what-I'm-doing" flag, but so far I can't find it in the manpage.
- Setting a `bindfs` over the `.ssh/` directory, but the problem is that the directory is non-empty (as it contains `known_hosts` and other data).
- `fuse-zip`-ing the keys over `/dev/shm` seems to be a possible path as well.

**EDIT**: As per @Gilles 's comment, yes, `bindfs` solves the issue. After a checking of the manpage, initial testing succeeded using the following invocation:

```
bindfs -n -r -p 0700 -o nonempty /run/media/myself/USB/.ssh/ ~/.ssh
```

Which binds disallowing access from other users (apparently even from `root`!), read-only, with reflected `0700` permissions. That reflection was the part that I lacked when working with bindfs originally. The `nonempty` flag was needed because of preexisting files such as `known_hosts`. This preserves the original workflow exactly except for an extra warning messae about not being able to add information to `known_hosts` (which in the end I might not mind).

Of course, I'm bindfs-ing to another directory now (in /dev/shm) as originally suggested to make things slightly easier.

I'm not as conspiranoid so as to `encfs` my USB drive (yet) so privacy-wise this is good enough for me.

Comment: Is there a way of telling your automounter to mount the stick with umask 077? (You usually don't care about permissions for group and others on a stick.)

Comment: To my knowledge it should be possible to do it via `udev` or similar (`hal`, `udisks`?), but I've found no good, centralized documentation on the process so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh-add` doesn't have an option to bypass its check of the key permissions. You could recompile the program and disable the check.

A bindfs should work. You don't need to mount it at `~/.ssh`, mount it at a special-purpose location and write a script that does `ssh-add ~/.ssh-private-keys-bindfs`.

Note that ssh is right in that your setup is pretty insecure. You must make sure never to plug that drive into a computer where you are not the sole user.

Comment: Good point about `bindfs`ing it at a different location, I'll test it.
And a better point about the security. While I'm the sole user of the _distro_, I'm not the sole user of the _physical_ computer.

Comment: @LuisMachuca If you're the only user of that operating system on that computer, you're probably fine (while hardware backdoors are possible in theory, they are not (yet?) common in the wild). But if there are other users using the same operating system (even if they aren't logged in at the same time as you), they can easily read your keys.

Comment: Luckily I'm not too concerned with HW backdoors (yet?). Laptops are too finicky for dongle-backdooring and at that point the attacker is close to me enough that on a practical level http://xkcd.com/538/ is more feasible.

Answer (score 3):

You can load the external key through the [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), e.g.

```
$ mkfifo -m=600 fifo
$ cat /external/media/.ssh/id_server_key >fifo | ssh-add fifo
```

Using process substitution also could work (using bash/zsh-like syntax):

```
$ ssh-add <(cat /external/media/.ssh/id_server_key)
```

<sup>Above command is equivalent to: `cat /external/media/.ssh/id_server_key | ssh-add -`.</sup>

assuming your [anonymous pipe has the right permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/235290/21471) (check via: `stat <(:)`).

Or try loading it from the standard input:

```
$ cat /external/media/.ssh/id_server_key | ssh-add -
```

Comment: `ssh-add <...` won't work, this will add `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (or similar) by default. Man: "When run without arguments, it adds the files ~/.ssh/id_rsa, ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/identity."

Comment: `ssh-add <(cat /foo/bar)` -> `cat: /foo/bar: No such file or directory`. This command expects external file in order to load. This syntax should work at least in Bash. Otherwise use standard syntax: `cat /foo/bar | ssh-add`.

Comment: You're right. I mis-read `<(cat file)` as `<file`. But now you're wrong too. `cat /foo/bar | ssh-add` won't add `/foo/bar`. Try `cat /dev/urandom | ssh-add`. My `ssh-add` adds `~/.ssh/id_rsa` in that case.

Comment: Forgot dash (`-`), `cat /dev/urandom | ssh-add -` -> `Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a permissions problem, as identified by this line:

> Permissions 0644 for 'id_server_key' are too open.

It happens, because your permissions are too open on the private key, then ssh cannot guarantee the authenticity of the key, and will balk at using it.

So taking into account the VFATness of the thumbdrive (which doesn't support changing the permissions), you could do something like adding this line into `/etc/fstab` file:

```
LABEL=USB none msdos -u=USERID,-m=PERMS
```

Where USERID is your numerical userid, and PERMS is 700.  This should tell the automounter to always mount the USB drive as that user, with no rights for group or other.

---

In case your file-system would support permissions, it would be much easier to fix it by:

```
chmod 700 /run/media/myself/USB/.ssh
chmod 400 /run/media/myself/USB/.ssh/id_server_key
```

Comment: The asker had already identified the problem. Your proposed solution doesn't work since this is a FAT filesystem that doesn't have file permissions.

Comment: ah. i missed the part about vfat.  thanks, @gilles.  someday i'll learn how to read more carefully. :)

Comment: I might try this one, though `bindfs` solved the problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 the following works just fine:

```
cat ~/.ssh/my-key.pem | ssh-add -
Identity added: (stdin) ((stdin))
```