# How to change permission of anonymous pipe?

Tags: bash, permissions, pipe, umask

I've the script which loads the SSH key from the variable (as part of script in CI environment) in order to not keep the private file in the public repository, however `ssh-add` complains about the wrong permissions (and [it seems it's not possible to bypass it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61008/21471)). So my approach is to find the method of changing the permission of anonymous pipe which is created on the fly.

For example:

```
$ stat <(:)
  File: ‘/dev/fd/63’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 512    fifo
Device: 397f3928h/964639016d    Inode: 818277067   Links: 0
Access: (0660/prw-rw----)  Uid: (  501/  kenorb)   Gid: (   20/   staff)
Access: 2015-10-10 22:33:30.498640000 +0100
Modify: 2015-10-10 22:33:30.498640000 +0100
Change: 2015-10-10 22:33:30.498640000 +0100
 Birth: 2015-10-10 22:33:30.498640000 +0100
```

shows `0660` permission. I've checked my `umask` and it seems it has nothing to do with that.

Here is a simple test (on OS X, which by default has 0660):

```
$ ssh-add <(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0660 for '/dev/fd/63' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

On Linux it seems to work, because it's `0500` by default. Where this permission is controlled from?

To clarify, I'm not looking to change the permission of any file, as I'd like to use an anonymous pipe.

The question is:

How do I temporary change the permission of a pipe?

Comment: A FIFO is a *named* pipe. You're having a problem because you have an (anonymous) pipe, not a FIFO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far I've found the following workaround using named FIFO:

```
$ mkfifo -m 600 fifo
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa >fifo | ssh-add fifo
Identity added: fifo (fifo)
```

where the option `-m` sets the FIFO permission.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to wrap `ssh-add` in a program which does a `chmod` on the `/dev/fd/N` path or `fchmod` on the file descriptor.

For example, on a Linux machine where I don't get any complaint from `ssh-add` using the default permissions, I'm able to reproduce the error by doing this:

```
perl -e 'chmod 0777, $ARGV[0];exec "ssh-add", $ARGV[0];' <(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

If that reproduces the problem, then this should solve it:

```
perl -e 'chmod 0600, $ARGV[0];exec "ssh-add", $ARGV[0];' <(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

The `chmod` is supplied with a pathname like `/proc/self/fd/11` but it changes the permissions on the actual pipe inode (since chmod doesn't work on symlinks). This should have the same effect, but using fchmod:

```
perl -e 'open P, "<", $ARGV[0]; chmod 0600, \*P;close P;exec "ssh-add", $ARGV[0];' <(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

This one should have the same effect, using fchmod and taking advantage of the fact that the pathname is in a predictable format to avoid the extra open:

```
perl -e '$ARGV[0] =~ m,^(?:/proc/self|/dev)/fd/(\d+)\z, and $^F=$1 and open P, "<&=$1" and chmod 0600, \*P;exec "ssh-add", $ARGV[0];' <(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Those perl scripts would look less ugly as C programs; converting them is simple once you identify one that works in your target environment.