# Why is ssh-add <(echo 'pk contents') not working?

Tags: shell, ssh, cat, process-substitution

I am getting this error:

> Permissions 0660 for '/dev/fd/63' are too open. It is required that
>   your private key files are NOT accessible by others. This private key
>   will be ignored.

when I run this:

```
ssh-add <(echo '<private key content>')
```

is there a way to change the permissions on the "file"?

Comment: am I? I guess ssh-add can read from stdin?

Comment: no, that doesn't work @GillesQuenot, instead it just adds the default key at ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: What's the use case? As in, why *not* write it to file?

Comment: I just felt like doing it that way so I didn't have to write it to a file

Comment: What would be the results on your system of these two commands? `ls -l <(echo test)` and `ls -lL <(echo test)` ?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear, and `man ssh-add` states:

```
 Identity files should not be readable by anyone but the user.  Note that
 ssh-add ignores identity files if they are accessible by others.
```

For some reason your file descriptor has 660, but needs 600 permissions. This is not the case for me, but I did yet not find a way to change that (maybe some `udev` rule).

You may use a pipe instead:

```
printf '%s' '<private key content>' | ssh-add -
```

---

Similar question:

- [How to change permission of anonymous pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235290/how-to-change-permission-of-anonymous-pipe)
- [GitLab WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE! Permissions 0660 for '/dev/fd/63' are too open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166990/gitlab-warning-unprotected-private-key-file-permissions-0660-for-dev-fd-63)