# (root) Warning: Identity file /dev/fd/62 not accessible: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, openssh, autossh

Very similar to [Failed to open config file '/dev/fd/63', error: No such file or directory for wpa_supplicant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279545/failed-to-open-config-file-dev-fd-63-error-no-such-file-or-directory-for-wp) except for the fact that I am running as root.

```
bash-4.4# autossh -v -M 0 -4 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -F <(echo "$VA_SOCKS_PROXY_SSH_CONFIG") -i <(echo "$VA_SOCKS_PROXY_PRIVATE_KEY") socks -D "0.0.0.0:2001" -N
```

> Warning: Identity file /dev/fd/62 not accessible: No such file or directory.
>   OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018
>   Can't open user config file /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory

The output is failing in two places. If I do a `ssh-add <(echo "$VA_SOCKS_PROXY_PRIVATE_KEY")` it works fine. Seems like the pipe is being read possibly by autossh first, then being read a second time by ssh (or vice versa) and therefore it is gone the second time.

UPDATE1: it appears running with just `ssh` reproduces same errors, so my hypothesis above is invalidated.

UPDATE2: This [comment](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/850#issuecomment-277482224) says:

> It seems `ssh` simply doesn’t support that mode of operation, because it closes FDs 3 and higher very early in `main()`

Comment: Maybe `mkfifo` work. (See also comment of [Specify private key in SSH as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041688/specify-private-key-in-ssh-as-string/16102792#16102792) or [SSH using keys in external storage - permissions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61006/ssh-using-keys-in-external-storage-permissions/235392#235392))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `ssh` closes all file descriptors early on in main() and as such does not support process substitution.

```
/*
 * Discard other fds that are hanging around. These can cause problem
 * with backgrounded ssh processes started by ControlPersist.
 */
closefrom(STDERR_FILENO + 1);
```

### Sources

- https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh.c#L621
- https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/c327813ea1d740e3e367109c17873815aba1328e/ssh.c#L621 (archive link)